# Unable to run pyspark: Failed to find Spark jars directory

Tags: macos, hadoop, pyspark

I have downloaded `spark-2.1.0-bin-without-hadoop` and it is in the following directory:

```
 ~/Desktop/ahajib/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-without-hadoop
```

When I go to that directory and then bin and try to run pyspark I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/pyspark: line 24: ~/Desktop/ahajib/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-without-hadoop/bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
/Users/ahajibagheri/Desktop/ahajib/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-without-hadoop/bin/spark-class: line 24: ~/Desktop/ahajib/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-without-hadoop/bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
Failed to find Spark jars directory (~/Desktop/ahajib/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-without-hadoop/assembly/target/scala-/jars).
You need to build Spark with the target "package" before running this program.
```

I have set both my JAVA_HOME and SPARK_HOME:

```
$JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
echo $SPARK_HOME
~/Desktop/ahajib/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-without-hadoop
```

I am running everything on macOS Sierra 10.12.6. Any help regarding this problem would be much appreciated. Let me know if I am missing something so I can update the question accordingly.

Thanks

Comment: Had to reinstall spark using the instructions given here:
https://gist.github.com/ololobus/4c221a0891775eaa86b0

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. To fix it I had to define `SPARK_HOME` without shortcut for the home directory (`~`). I think in your case it should be like this:

```
export SPARK_HOME="/Users/ahajibagheri/Desktop/ahajib/opt/spark-2.1.0-bin-without-hadoop"
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I install spark by `pip3 install pyspark`, and the error caused by incorrect `SPARK_HOME` variable. It works when I run command like below:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark python3 wordcount.py a.txt
```

Comment: Where the `wordcount.py` file is.